# Benefit of applying tf.image.per_image_standardization() over batch_norm layer in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

What is the benefit in applying `tf.image.per_image_standardization()` before the first layer of the deep neural network **over** adding the `Batch_Norm layer` as the first layer?

In order to normalize the [0.0, 255.0] float value image pixels before feeding into the network, which method would be suitable?

1. tf.image.per_image_standardization()
2. Batch_Norm - layer

Answer (score 0):

They both do similar things, and one could indeed use batch norm to normalize input images.

However, I would not use batch norm for this purpose:

- It is clearer to use `tf.image.per_image_standardization` for image normalization than batch norm.
- Batch normalization is a broader concept than a per-channel normalization. Libraries like tensorflow let you normalize along any axis you want.
- Batch normalization is usually paired with streaming statistics of the means and variances used for normalization, that are meant to be used for testing and deployement. You don't need those statistics when you normalize your input image per sample.